# Unable to do a POST request to my API using flutter and http client

Tags: node.js, flutter, api, rest, dart

I was building a Todo application in Flutter, with a custom API that I built using Node.js, planetscale(MySQL), and Prisma. The API is complete.

Now I was implementing the frontend, but for some reason, I am unable to POST data through the HTTP client in Flutter. I am able to create data using postman. The GET function is working fine.

Here is the model file

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

List<Item> itemFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Item>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Item.fromJson(x)));

String itemToJson(List<Item> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Item {
  Item({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.description,
    this.color,
    this.completed,
    this.priority,
    this.itemImage,
    this.itemLink,
    this.dateTime,
  });

  int? id;
  String title;
  String? description;
  String? color;
  bool? completed;
  bool? priority;
  String? itemImage;
  String? itemLink;
  DateTime? dateTime;

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        id: json["id"],
        title: json["title"],
        description: json["description"],
        color: json["color"],
        completed: json["completed"],
        priority: json["priority"],
        itemImage: json["itemImage"],
        itemLink: json["itemLink"],
        dateTime: DateTime.parse(json["dateTime"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "color": color,
        "completed": completed,
        "priority": priority,
        "itemImage": itemImage,
        "itemLink": itemLink,
        "dateTime": dateTime?.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

Here is the client class

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const String BASE = "xxx";

class BaseClient {
  var client = http.Client();

  Future<dynamic> get(String api) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(BASE + api);
    var res = await client.get(url);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      return res.body;
    } else {
      // error
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(String api, dynamic object) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(BASE + api);
    var _payload = json.encode(object);
    var _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'};
    var res = await client.post(url, body: _payload, headers: _headers);
    if (res.statusCode == 201) {
      return res.body;
    } else {
      // error
    }
  }

  Future<dynamic> put(String api) async {}
  Future<dynamic> delete(String api) async {}
}
```

This is the small section of the main UI's file

```dart
...
CustomButton(
              opr: "GET",
              desc: "Fetch Items",
              color: Colors.green.shade400,
              onPressed: () async {
                var res = await BaseClient().get('/').catchError((e) {});
                if (res == null) return;
                debugPrint('successfull');

                var items = itemFromJson(res);
                debugPrint('Items count: ' + items.length.toString());
              },
            ),
            CustomButton(
              opr: "POST",
              desc: "Create Items",
              color: Colors.blue.shade400,
              onPressed: () async {
                var item = Item(
                  title: "Complete Project",
                  color: "blue",
                  completed: false,
                  priority: true,
                  itemImage: "",
                  itemLink: "",
                  dateTime: DateTime.now(),
                );
                var res =
                    await BaseClient().post('/create', item).catchError((e) {
                  debugPrint(e);
                });
                if (res == null) return debugPrint("Response was nothing");
                debugPrint('successfull');
              },
            ),
...
```

When I click on the GET Button I get `Items count: 7`, but when I click on the POST button I get `Response was nothing`

Kindly look into the code and please do the needful. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try after add some data in the       itemImage: "",
                  itemLink: "", ?

Comment: Thanks for the response mate, but sadly this also didn't work. The same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass model class direct in to API call. Please pass like this.

```
  var item = {
    "title": "Complete Project",
    "color": "blue",
    "completed": false,
    "priority": true,
    'itemImage': "",
    "itemLink": "",
    "dateTime": DateTime.now()
  };
```